# Combining two Turing machines

Tags: turing-machines

Is there a way of combining two turing machines without introducing an extra state (I don't want to increase or decrease the total number of states)? Don't worry about an accept or a reject state since they are not that important; I just want a TM to do some computation starting from a blank tape, and I want the result of that computation (some tape contents) to be used by the next TM right after the first machine halts  (i.e output redirection)

The only solution I can think of (without introducing a new state) is that I combine the halt state of first machine and the initial state of the second machine into one state, but I am decreasing the total number of states by 1.

Comment: what transitions are you allowing? a do nothing state transition is allowed for some definition of turing machine

Comment: Just a normal turing machine.Read/write tape symbol and move the head left or right.